# cannot create object from external .jar library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

when i try to create an object and run the app i get this error:
i use: api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process
>   C:\Android\xxxxxx\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\1.jar
>
> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error
>   while dexing
>   target/test-classes/com/xxxxxx/services/request/ValidateOtpRQ.class
>
> Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name
>   (com/xxxxxx/services/request/ValidateOtpRQ) does not match path
>   (target/test-classes/com/xxxxxx/services/request/ValidateOtpRQ.class)
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.